# Sending Image from c# whatsapp api

Tags: c#, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'am trying to send image from whatsapp api c# application
there is the code :

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
wa.SendMessageImage(user.GetFullJid() + "@s.whatsapp.net", buffer, ApiBase.ImageType.GIF);
MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

it gives me error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   WhatsAppApi.dll
>
> Additional information: BinTreeNodeReader->readListSize: Invalid token 231

Comment: The error message says that the token is invalid, so I would start looking at the token if I were you.

Comment: Here is the similar issue. https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/411 You have to investigate the behaviour when the exception occures.

Comment: I want to send image message not text .. text is running good but images not ...